# universal reference vs const reference priority?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, reference, universal-reference

When I consider the two following overloads:

```
template <class... T> void f(const T&... x);
template <class T> void f(const T& x);
```

I have the guarantee that `f(x)` will always call the second function and will never lead to an ambiguity. In a sense the second version is universally prioritized compared to the first one for one argument whatever its type is.

Now consider the situation where there is a universal reference and a const reference versions of a function:

```
template <class T> void f(T&& x);
template <class T> void f(const T& x);
```

My question is: is their a universal priority between these two functions regardless of the type of x (r-value reference, reference, cv-qualifiers, pointer...) like in the previous case? (and if yes, what is the priority ?)

Comment: I think it was [this talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5swP3dr190) that included this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is not a universal priority between these two functions.  They compete equally in the overload resolution algorithm.  In general the so-called "universal reference" wins unless `const T&` is an exact match, and there the `const T&` wins.

```
struct A {};

int
main()
{
    f(std::declval<A>());  // calls f<A>(A&&), #1
    f(std::declval<const A>());  // calls f<const A>(const A&&), #1
    f(std::declval<A&>());  // calls f<A&>(A&), #1
    f(std::declval<A&&>());  // calls f<A>(A&&), #1
    f(std::declval<const A&&>());  // calls f<const A>(const A&&), #1
    f(std::declval<const A&>());  // calls f<A>(const A&), #2
}
```

Good advice is to **never** overload like this.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning which of these cases (if any) #2 was never a candidate to begin with.

Comment: @BenVoigt Unless I'm missing something, both overloads are viable in all these expressions.

Comment: @aschepler: I think you're right.  Maybe it is `T&&` vs `T&` that ends up being surprising.

Comment: Note the technical term "Exact Match" (13.3.3.1.1) applies to all twelve implicit conversion sequences.  Might be safer to say "wins unless the argument is a `const` lvalue".

Comment: I'm not sure, but doesn't `f(std::declval<const A&&>());` actually call `f<const A>(const A&&)`?